How to increase RestAssured timeout to 120 sec?
If I get response for more than 1 minute(60 sec) - anyway I get 504 Timeout Error. These params works only for decreasing the time from 60 sec. I need to do vice versa. Can you help me to set up timeout within RestAssured and preferable using RequestSpecBuilder
import io.restassured.config.HttpClientConfig;
import io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig;
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.filter.log.LogDetail;
import io.restassured.filter.Filter;
import io.restassured.filter.log.RequestLoggingFilter;
import io.restassured.filter.log.ResponseLoggingFilter;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SpecificationFactory {

    public static RestAssuredConfig config = RestAssuredConfig.config()
            .httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                    .setParam("http.connection.timeout", (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(120))
                    .setParam("http.socket.timeout", (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(120))
                    .setParam("http.connection-manager.timeout", (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(120)));

    private SpecificationFactory() {
    }

    public static RequestSpecification getDefaultRequestSpecification(String serviceName) {
        return new RequestSpecBuilder()
                .setConfig(config)
                .setBaseUri(UrlConfig.getUrl(ENV, serviceName))
                .addHeader(Headers.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, String.format(Headers.AUTHORIZATION_BEARER, ACCESS_TOKEN))
                .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .setAccept(ContentType.JSON)
                .log(LogDetail.ALL)
                .addFilter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
                .addFilter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
                .build()
                .filter(new AllureRestAssured());
    }
}
     ```

I tried to increase timeout in my RestAssured class by setting the params, but it won't help



504 is server-side error (whatever starts from 5). When you call the endpoint the server cannot receive the result of downstream request in acceptable time thus responding with 504.
See the details of this particular error here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504
So there is no way to control server timeout config on HTTP-client side.

Probably not in this case, because we investigate this issue many times. In some cases an our server gives the response within 1.5-2 minutes whilst I get the 504 in exactly one minute so that from my side it's considering as Timeout Error, but if I wait more than 1 minute - I'll get success probably
